# Apache cannot initialize Passenger. Broken pipe (32) when connecting to Application Pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, phusion

I have installed Phusion Passenger 2.0.3 on Apache 2.2.3 on Centos 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP and I am getting the following on the httpd error log

```
Cannot initialize Passenger in an Apache child process: Could not connect to the ApplicationPool server: Broken pipe (32)
```

I have removed the modules that Passenger conflicts with as per the [documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#conflicting_apache_modules).

Thoughts?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following tutorial for setting up Passenger correctly:
[Deploying to a virtual host](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root)

I had the same issue with Enterprise Ruby and Passenger

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was because accidentally installed the native package (debian in my case) and also the gem. So for some reason it was causing the conflict. I removed the package and restarted Apache and it worked. Hope that helps.